# Change slider to select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having issues trying to figure out how to change my bmi calculator from a slide to a select box and then passing that input to have it be calculated.

For the feet I have the inches set as the values and then when inches are selected they need to be added on to the feet for a total.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="height-ft">Feet</label>
        <select name="height-ft" id="height-ft" class="form-control">
            <option value="12">1'</option>
            <option value="24">2'</option>
            <option value="36">3'</option>
            <option value="48">4'</option>
            <option value="60">5'</option>
            <option value="72">6'</option>
            <option value="84">7'</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="height-in">Inches</label>
        <select name="height-in" id="height-in" class="form-control">
            <option value="1">1"</option>
            <option value="2">2"</option>
            <option value="3">3"</option>
            <option value="4">4"</option>
            <option value="5">5"</option>
            <option value="6">6"</option>
            <option value="7">7"</option>
            <option value="8">7"</option>
            <option value="9">9"</option>
            <option value="10">7"</option>
            <option value="11">7"</option>
        </select>   
    </div>
```

**JS Fiddle:**
Working example with the jquery ui slide.
http://jsfiddle.net/ypyxrks8/

Anyone help with converting this over would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may need to pass the select values to a hidden input field to be processed but not sure on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically had it. That slider is doing some stuff to get values, but you can get the values with parseInt(). I had to add a conversion factor to get it correct, and you'll need to fill in your discrete values for weight, but here is the code:

[HTML]

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"> <strong>Height:</strong>

        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="height-ft" id="height-ft" class="form-control">
                <option value="12">1'</option>
                <option value="24">2'</option>
                <option value="36">3'</option>
                <option value="48">4'</option>
                <option value="60">5'</option>
                <option value="72">6'</option>
                <option value="84">7'</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="height-in" id="height-in" class="form-control">
                <option value="1">1"</option>
                <option value="2">2"</option>
                <option value="3">3"</option>
                <option value="4">4"</option>
                <option value="5">5"</option>
                <option value="6">6"</option>
                <option value="7">7"</option>
                <option value="8">7"</option>
                <option value="9">9"</option>
                <option value="10">10"</option>
                <option value="11">11"</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12"> <strong>Weight:</strong>

        <select name="weight-in" id="weight-in" class="form-control">
            <option value="100">100</option>
            <option value="120">120</option>
            <option value="140">140</option>
            <option value="160">160</option>
            <option value="180">180</option>
            <option value="200">200</option>
            <option value="220">220</option>
            <option value="240">240</option>
            <option value="260">260</option>
            <option value="280">280</option>
            <option value="300">300</option>
        </select>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div type="button" id="calculatebutton" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate</div>
    <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

[CSS]

```
/* BMI Calculator */

 $('#calculatebutton').click(function () {
 var weight = parseInt($('#weight-in').val()),
     heightInches = parseInt($('#height-ft').val()) + parseInt($('#height-in').val()),
     heightsqaured = (heightInches) * (heightInches),
     result = ((weight) / (heightsqaured) * 703);
 debugger;
 if (result < 16) {
     var rating = ('You are severely underweight');
 } else if (result > 16 && result < 18.5) {
     var rating = ('You are underweight');
 } else if (result > 18.5 && result < 25) {
     var rating = ('You are healthy');
 } else if (result > 25 && result < 30) {
     var rating = ('You are overweight');
 } else if (result > 30 && result < 35) {
     var rating = ('You are moderately obese');
 } else if (result > 35 && result < 40) {
     var rating = ('You are severely obese');
 } else if (result > 40 && result < 80) {
     var rating = ('You are very severely obese');
 } else if (result > 80) {
     var rating = ('This result seems unlikely, please check that the information you have entered is correct');
 }
 $('#result').html('Your BMI is ' + result.toFixed(1) + '. ' + rating + '.');
```

});

Working version here: https://jsfiddle.net/W3AVE/ypyxrks8/7/

Answer (score 1):

If all you are looking help for is adding the inches to the feet then add this line of code to your calculate button click:

```
   var total = parseInt($('#height-ft').val()) +  parseInt($('#height-in').val());
```

That gives you the total number of inches.